# Java method for increasing all animal and owner objects age by 1

Tags: java

Hi im working with my friends on a school project of animal garden. We have animal class, dog, cat and turtle class that inherit from animal class. I also have owner class.  I can`t solve method to increase all animals and owners by age 1. The metod would be initiated in menu class
owner class

```
import java.io.Serializable;


public class Owner implements Serializable {
    private String name, surname; 
    private char gender; 
    private int age;

    @Override public String toString() {
        return name + " "+ surname + ", "+ gender+ ", "+age;
    }
```

animal class

```
import java.io.Serializable;


public class Animal  implements Serializable {
    protected String name; 
    protected char gender; 
    protected int age; 
    protected Point actualPosition;
    protected Owner owner;
  
    public Animal(){
        this.actualPosition = new Point(0,0);
    }
    
    public boolean move(int x, int y){

        this.actualPosition.x += x; 
        this.actualPosition.y += y; 

      
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What is blocking you from adding a method to `Animal` and `Owner` that increases the age by one?

Comment: I don't know much about serialization but don't we need the UID in the classes too.

Answer (score 2):

Create getter and setter for the age and owner in the animal class.
Then add the same getter and setter for the age to the owner class.

```
public Owner getOwner() {
    return this.owner;
}

public void setOwner(Owner owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}

public int getAge() {
    return this.age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

Now you can create some where this method to increase the age by a value like one.

```
public static void increaseBothAges(Animal animal, int value) {
    animal.setAge(animal.getAge() + value);
    Owner owner = animal.getOwner();
    owner.setAge(owner.getAge() + value);
}
```

Comment: replace `years` with `value`

Comment: I have getters and setter i just cut them off , to much code in post add they are from InteliJ generator . Can`t use static and that makes me a problem.